# audisp-remote signal USR1 works as root, not with sudo

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo, syslog, auditd

So I have a weird problem that I'm running out of ideas to troubleshoot.

My RedHat machines are using `audisp-remote` to send syslog messages to a central server.  `audisp-remote` will respond to the `USR1` signal by dumping a line of status info into `/var/log/messages`, like this:

```
$ sudo kill -USR1 `pidof audisp-remote`
```

> Oct 16 13:17:19 hostname audisp-remote: suspend=no, transport_ok=yes, queue_size=0

This works great on all of my machines except one.  On this one machine, I get this:

```
$ sudo kill -USR1 `pidof audisp-remote`
```

> Oct 16 13:22:20 hostname audisp-remote: read from
>   server.fq.dn failed
>
> Oct 16 13:22:20 hostname audisp-remote: Error connecting to server.fq.dn: Cannot assign
>   requested address

But on the other hand, if I do this:

```
$ sudo su
# kill -USR1 `pidof audisp-remote`
```

Then it works correctly

> Oct 16 13:25:29 hostname audisp-remote: suspend=no, transport_ok=yes, queue_size=0

I can't figure out why the problem only affects this one machine -- the only reason I can think of is that this machine is on a remote network in a remote location -- but that doesn't explain why it works as root but not under `sudo` .